# How to turn rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help resolve this problem, rows to column? I'm using SQL Server 2019.

This is my source table:

| machine_code | empno | punch_code | punch_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 0 | 2024-02-01 07:58:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 3 | 2024-02-01 17:06:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 0 | 2024-02-02 07:53:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 3 | 2024-02-02 17:05:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 0 | 2024-02-03 07:49:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 2 | 2024-02-03 16:04:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 0 | 2024-02-05 07:52:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 3 | 2024-02-05 17:05:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 0 | 2024-02-06 07:53:00.000 |
| 6 | 0000000001 | 3 | 2024-02-06 17:05:00.000 |

I use this script but the output is not aligned, I want that the same date is aligned.

```
SELECT 
    empno,
    [0] as [punch_code0],
    [1] as [punch_code1],
    [2] as [punch_code2],
    [3] as [punch_code3], 
    [4] as [punch_code4],
    [5] as [punch_code5]
FROM 
    biometric_log
PIVOT 
    (MAX(punch_date) FOR punch_code IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS pvt
```

This is the output

```
empno   punch_code0 punch_code1 punch_code2 punch_code3 punch_code4 punch_code5
0000000001  2024-02-01 07:58:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0000000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    2024-02-01 17:06:00.000 NULL    NULL
0000000001  2024-02-02 07:53:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0000000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    2024-02-02 17:05:00.000 NULL    NULL
0000000001  2024-02-03 07:49:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0000000001  NULL    NULL    2024-02-03 16:04:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL
0000000001  2024-02-05 07:52:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0000000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    2024-02-05 17:05:00.000 NULL    NULL
0000000001  2024-02-06 07:53:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0000000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    2024-02-06 17:05:00.000 NULL    NULL
```

I want the output should look like this

```
empno      punch_code0         punch_code1 punch_code2 punch_code3
0000000001 2024-02-01 07:58:00 NULL    NULL        2024-02-01 17:06:00
0000000001 2024-02-02 07:53:00 NULL    NULL        2024-02-02 17:05:00
0000000001 2024-02-03 07:49:00 NULL    NULL        2024-02-03 16:04:00
0000000001 2024-02-05 07:52:00 NULL        NULL        2024-02-05 17:05:00
0000000001 2024-02-06 07:53:00 NULL        NULL        2024-02-06 17:05:00
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happen to `2024-02-03 16:04:00.000` for `punch_code` `2`?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on the should be output table, 2024-02-03 16:04:00.000 will be aligned to column punch_code2. Thank you.

Comment: It appears that you wish the output to have one row per date (ignoring time).  Could an employee ever have the same punch code more than once on the same date?

Comment: Yes Sir, one row per date (ignoring time), and the employee could have same punch code on the same date but the latest time will prevail, discarding the previous punch code.

Comment: If you add a `CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(punch_date AS DATE) AS date) d` before the pivot, this will as a date-only value to the pivot results that I believe will yield your desired results.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l2dfHgyR).

Comment: Looking at your current output, you have other columns in the table beside those that you have shown. use a `CTE` or sub-query to select only the required column.  Also add the `CAST(punch_date AS DATE)` that `T N` suggested

Comment: I tried the script given by T N but got same result, as my previous script, thank you.

Comment: [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xyaVUAmF) includes an extra distinct `id` column that demonstrates the issue that @Squirrel pointed out, along with his suggested fixes (both subquery and CTE forms).